Optimizely: Content with id '2809' has a property with scopename '20880' but there is no entry in IPropertyDefinitionRepository with that id
Does any of you know how I can get all the contentProperties with scopename that does not exist?
I like to create a schedule job, to cleanup old references.
I get this warning I like to fix: "Content with id '2809' has a property with scopename '20880' but there is no entry in IPropertyDefinitionRepository with that id"
I can see the db has some contentProperties with scopename that does not exist.
But I dont know how to get this in C# code - only at database level.
Thanks for your help.
I have tried to get the scopename from optimizely c# sdk. But cannot see there are any way to do it.

Johan Björnfot answered this question on world a while ago:
"The values in the scopename are the ids of the property definition."
https://world.optimizely.com/forum/developer-forum/CMS/Thread-Container/2018/5/warnings-after-upgrade-from-cms-10-to-11/
